# How to build MongoDB connector for hadoop latest version (1.2.1)

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, mongodb-java, hadoop-plugins

I'm trying to build the MongoDB connector for Hadoop 1.2.1 from the montogdb instruction page (https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop) but i'm getting following error. one thing to mention, hadoop 1.2.1 is not included in the list of supported version. I tried to install 1.1 but it is not included in hadoop download page or any of the mirrors, anyone has an ideal if it is possible to build the connector for hadoop 1.2.1?

```
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1: configuration not found in commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1: 'compile'. It was required from commons-configuration#commons-configuration;1.6 compile
at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:214)
at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:122)
at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:121)
at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:114)
at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:114)
at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:102)
at sbt.IvySbt.liftedTree1$1(Ivy.scala:49)
at sbt.IvySbt.action$1(Ivy.scala:49)
at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:58)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:75)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:58)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:79)
at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.liftedTree1$1(Locks.scala:51)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:51)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:30)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:27)
at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:58)
at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:99)
at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:95)
at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:114)
at sbt.IvyActions$.update(IvyActions.scala:121)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:951)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:949)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$54.apply(Defaults.scala:972)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$54.apply(Defaults.scala:970)
at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:35)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:974)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:969)
at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:45)
at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:977)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$45.apply(Defaults.scala:856)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$45.apply(Defaults.scala:853)
at sbt.Scoped$$anonfun$hf10$1.apply(Structure.scala:586)
at sbt.Scoped$$anonfun$hf10$1.apply(Structure.scala:586)
at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:49)
at sbt.Scoped$Reduced$$anonfun$combine$1$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Structure.scala:311)
at sbt.Scoped$Reduced$$anonfun$combine$1$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Structure.scala:311)
at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:41)
at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$5.work(System.scala:71)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:238)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
 [error] (mongo-hadoop-core/*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1: configuration not found in commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1: 'compile'. It was required from commons-configuration#commons-configuration;1.6 compile
[error] Total time: 18 s, completed Sep 3, 2013 8:04:37 PM
```

thanks so much

Comment: You'll need to make sure commons-logging is on your classpath somehow.  You need to add it to your Ivy dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can find older hadoop releases on the archive server.  I was able to get the mongodb hadoop connector working with version 1.1.2.

http://archive.apache.org/dist/hadoop/core/ or there's an archive link at the top of the page on any mirror.